# Setup Screen of Trail Tracker in Salesforce

Tags: trailhead

I wanted to know when you go into the Setup Screen for Trail Tracker in Salesforce it asks for Credentials. I wanted to confirm what credentials it requires (is this the org that users are completing their trails in?) and when I fill out these credentials what permissions I am granting or what access I am allowing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through the [Installation Guide](https://quip.com/AVc8Aouc4Lzx), you will need to create an *Integration User* and need to provide the credentials for that particular User in the Setup process.

> Make sure you have the login credentials handy for the Integration User you created earlier.

The Installation Guide also mentions to create a special permission set and only provide API access to it so that you do not expose any data from your Org. Refer to the **Create an Integration User** section of the Installation Guide, which should provide you with more details.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - thank you!